# php simple_html_dom not fetching content in proper order

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I m back with another screen scraping problem. I m using simple_html_dom.php for screen scraping.I m pasting the code the,response text and 2nd response text. these responses are the result which simple_html_dom is providing me.it would look to u that response is ok,but its not. actually there will be a link..which my request is going and u can manually see what are the results(in ur browser) and what simple_html_dom is giving me.

So lets first see the code.

here se is search_engine ,$key is keyword(say digital signage)

```
function search_company_name( $com_id, $string, $c , $fetched )//----Function: search company name in resultant string
{
    foreach($com_id AS $company => $id)
    {
        if(preg_match('/www\.'.$company.'/', $string)>0)
        {           
            return array('id' => $id,'rank' => $c+1,'fetched' => $fetched+1);
            break;            
        }        
    }    
    return NULL;   
}


if($se === 'google.com' || $se === 'google.co.in' || $se === 'google.de' || $se === 'google.nl'|| $se === 'google.co.uk')
{    
    $count = 0;       //---- Count the rank ----//
    //----LOOP FOR 2 PAGES OF 100 RESULTS----//
    for($num_of_results = 0; $num_of_results < 200; $num_of_results += 100)
    {
        var_dump('http://www.'.$se.'/search?q='.$key.'&start='.$num_of_results.'&num=100');// **check the link urself in ur browser**
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.'.$se.'/search?q='.$key.'&start='.$num_of_results.'&num=10');

        foreach($html->find('div[id=ires] ol li') as $row)
        {            
            $string = $row->plaintext;
            $temp = search_company_name($company_rank, $string, $count, $counter);            
            if(!is_null($temp))
            {
                reset($temp);
                array_push($finalData, $temp);
                foreach($company_rank as $company => $id)
                {
                    if($temp[id] == $id)
                    {
                        unset($company_rank[$company]);break;
                    }
                }
                $counter++;
            }
            unset($temp);
            if ($tot_company == $counter)
            {
                break;
            }
            $count++;
        }
        if($tot_company == $counter)
        {
            break;
        }
        $html->clear();
        sleep(3);
    }
}
```

code is fyn and works to.now pasting two responses.

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Digital+Signage&amp;start=0&amp;num=10'</font> <i>(length=63)</i>
</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Digital signage - Wikipedia, the free encyclopediaDigital signage is a form of electronic display that shows information, advertising and other messages. Digital signs (such as LCD, LED, plasma displays , ...Market and applications - Companies - Content - Technologyen.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signage - Cached - Similar'</font> <i>(length=322)</i>
</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'Digital Signage | KiosksDynamic, enterprise digital signage software and hardware solutions for simple and complex digital out-of-home (DOOH) installations scaled to  any sized ...www.digitalsignage.com/ - Cached - Similar'</font> <i>(length=222)</i>
```

as u can see there are two li response(check urself).these result are text of 1st li and 5li. so where 2-4 li hav gone??it is working correctly for 'digital signage software' in google. Plz help me.my project is near end and i got stucked in this silly prob.

second response may not lead me to post question.

Comment: May be the search engine is returning two different sets of results for searches that you make from your computer and those made on the server. Remember, search results are location specific... searches made from India might return different results than those made from US.

Comment: When I search these results, it is actually for 1 and 2, not 1 and 5. It seems the rankings have been altered

Comment: @Salman - Thats a very valid point. @Aakash are you running the code from the same machine you're searching google from?

Comment: i know it is coming similar in browser but simple_html_dom or even file_get_content is not retrieving same results as available in search engines. check urself(file_get_content and echo it.compare it in different google se). I was wrong at some point but after testing it against different keywords and different google's se, found different.

Answer (score 0):

Google returns differently structured results based on your user-agent. Find out your user-agent [here](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/), and then set your script to use the same.

Your IP address can determine which Google page is displayed, which may have different layouts.